# Gunicorn in .sh file could not import python packages installed

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sh, gunicorn

I am using gunicorn to deploy a flask application, and I have put the complete command for gunicorn in a `.sh` file. But it seems that the python imports I have used in the project, are not getting imported hen running using `.sh` file. Without it, I am able to import it. I think the issue is with gunicorn. I am using `gunicorn3` and `python3.6`

This happened with first `flask` import, so I installed flask's .deb file on the system, then started with other packages. So, my deduction is that it should be gunicorn issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I created a virtual environment and installed gunicorn over there and used that gunicorn instead of gunicorn3, it worked.